# ViewModel does not get updated in the layout when setters are called from method other than onCreate()

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a class named `MyInfoModel` that has some instance variables in it to store data about the user and a method to notify the observers of the class.

```
private final List<ObserverInterface> observers = new ArrayList<>();
private int id;
private String name;
private String imageURL;

// Getters, Setters, Register and Unregister Methods for Instance Variables
// Also All Setter Methods call the notifyObservers() method after setting the values

private void notifyObservers(){
   Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Notifying All Observers");
   for (ObserverInterface observer : observers){
        observer.updateViews();
   }
}
```

I have an interface `ObserverInterface` that has only one method `void updateViews();` which is overridden by other classes that implement this interface.

I am using Retrofit to request some data which gets updated in a static object in the Constants class.

```
public class Constants {
   public static MyInfoModel INFO_CONSTANTS = new MyInfoModel();
}
```

Also, I have a View Model `MainActivityViewModel` that extends `ViewModel` class and has variables, getters and setters to support the layout of the activity.

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String imageURL;

// Getters and Setters
```

I have used DataBinding in my layout like this

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.itsyourap.app.viewModel.MainActivityViewModel" />
    </data>

<TextView <!-- Layout Tags -->
         android:text="@{viewModel.Name}" />
```

Then I have the `MainActivity` where I want to wait for any change in the values of variables of `Constants.INFO_CONSTANTS`, so I implement the `ObserverInterface` interface and Override the `updateViews()` method like this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObserverInterface {

    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        mainBinding.setViewModel(mainViewModel);
        mainBinding.getViewModel().setName("Alpha Beta Gamma"); // Works
        mainBinding.getViewModel().setImageURL("somelink.jpg"); // Works
    }

    public MainActivity(){
        Constants.INFO_CONSTANTS.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateViews() {
        if (mainViewModel != null){
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Updating Views");
            mainViewModel.setName(Constants.INFO_CONSTANTS.getName()); // Does Not Work
            mainViewModel.setImageURL(Constants.INFO_CONSTANTS.getImageURL()); // Does Not Work
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing that the `updateViews()` is called successfully (according to LogCat) but the Layout isn't updated at the runtime. I have tried using `LiveData` and `MutableLiveData` but they do not seem to work as well. Also I tried using `mainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);` but it didn't work as well.

Also calling the setters from the `onCreate()` method works perfectly but does not work from the `updateViews()` method.

How should I make it work? I just want the values in the layout to change as soon as the values in the ViewModel gets changed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why you going with all this trouble creating a custom observable and all . Can't you use a LiveData ?

Comment: Tried using! But still doesn't work. It works when setters are called from the `onCreate()` but not from the `updateViews()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `setViewModel()` after modifying the variables solves the issue

```
@Override
    public void updateViews() {
        if (mainViewModel != null){
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Updating Views");
            mainViewModel.setName(Constants.INFO_CONSTANTS.getName());
            mainViewModel.setImageURL(Constants.INFO_CONSTANTS.getImageURL()); 
            mainBinding.setViewModel(mainViewModel); // Solves The Problem
        }
    }
```